# Flask web: can not open the site by domain name

Tags: nginx, flask, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I have deployed my flask Web in AWS ubuntu ec2 using Nginx, supervisor, and gunicorn.
Some strange points:
(1) Sometimes I can access my site by the domain name in the safari browser, but after some time, I can not access it by the domain name. The accessed site images by the domain name (test.com)will be the following one:

```
      test.com
parked free, courtesy of GoDaddy.com.
```

(2) I can access it by IP address using the all browsers.

(3) sometimes I tried another browsers, it can be accessed by the domain. but after I while, the same issue as (1).
My setting files as follows:

sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    # root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    # index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name test.com; # 
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log; 
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; 
        proxy_redirect off;
        
        proxy_set_header Host           $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real_IP      $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;        
    }
    

    location /static { # 
        alias /home/ubuntu/blog/app/static/;
        expires 30d; # 
        
    }
    
}
```

sudo vim /etc/supervisor/conf.d/blog.conf

```
[program:flask-blog-owner]
command=/home/ubuntu/blog/bash.sh
directory=/home/ubuntu/blog
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```

bash.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu/blog
exec gunicorn -w 4 wsgi:app
```

DNS information in Godaddy

Records
Last updated 29/10/21 4:35 PM

```
Type    Name    Value   TTL Actions
A   @   xx.xx.x.x   1/2 Hour    Edit
A   @   Parked  600 seconds Edit
CNAME   www @   1 Hour  Edit
CNAME   _domainconnect  _domainconnect.gd.domaincontrol.com 1 Hour  Edit
NS  @   ns23.domaincontrol.com  1 Hour  
NS  @   ns24.domaincontrol.com  1 Hour  
SOA @   Primary nameserver: ns23.domaincontrol.com. 1 Hour
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it ! Just deleted Parked value DNS setting in the domain name setting of your godaddy account. This may cause the above issue.